# How can i debug in getAllowedMethods for custom shipping method?

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods

How can i debug in custom shipping method?

```
<?php
namespace Inchoo\Shipping\Model\Carrier;

use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest;
use Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result;


class Example extends \Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\AbstractCarrier implements
    \Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\CarrierInterface
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_code = 'example';

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\ErrorFactory $rateErrorFactory
     * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
     * @param \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory $rateResultFactory
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory $rateMethodFactory
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\ErrorFactory $rateErrorFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory $rateResultFactory,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory $rateMethodFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_rateResultFactory = $rateResultFactory;
        $this->_rateMethodFactory = $rateMethodFactory;
        parent::__construct($scopeConfig, $rateErrorFactory, $logger, $data);
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAllowedMethods()
    {
        $allowed = explode(',', $this->getConfigData('shipcode'));
        $arr = array();
        foreach ($allowed as $k) {
            $arr[$k] = $k;
        }

        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/testshipping.log');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);
        $logger->info($arr.'abc');

        return ['example' => $this->getConfigData('name')];
    }

    /**
     * @param RateRequest $request
     * @return bool|Result
     */
    public function collectRates(RateRequest $request)
    {
        if (!$this->getConfigFlag('active')) {
            return false;
        }

        /** @var \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result $result */
        $result = $this->_rateResultFactory->create();

        /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\Method $method */
        $method = $this->_rateMethodFactory->create();

        $method->setCarrier('example');
        $method->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));

        $method->setMethod('example');
        $method->setMethodTitle($this->getConfigData('name'));

        /*you can fetch shipping price from different sources over some APIs, we used price from config.xml - xml node price*/
        $amount = $this->getConfigData('price');

        $method->setPrice($amount);
        $method->setCost($amount);

        $result->append($method);

        return $result;
    }
}
```

i placed the code inside the getAllowedMethods() but nothing was happened, the payment method still display

```
    $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/testshipping.log');
    $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
    $logger->addWriter($writer);
    $logger->info($arr.'abc');
```

Anyone know how to debug in getAllowedMethods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$this->debugData($arr)
```

That method exists in `Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\AbstractCarrier` file.

Comment: where the bug output data will be stored?

Comment: in `var/log/debug.log` file.